# Multi-Tenant Rails 3 App on Heroku using PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, mongodb, heroku, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant app on Heroku (multiple Accounts that know nothing about each other), and I'm unsure as how to best architect my database.  Postgres's schemas [look awesome](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/07/building-multi-tenant-rails-apps-with-postgresql-schemas/), but heroku doesn't handle [large numbers of them well](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-multiple-schema-support).

Now, my Rails app is mainly serving JSON, as most of the templates are rendering client-side (using Backbone.js).  So I'm considering moving to MongoDB because 1) each tenant could get one top level 'account' document, and everything could be nested below and 2) its storage format so closely resembles JSON.  We are still in beta, so it could be pulled off.  Are those valid reasons to use Mongo?  Is former even an intelligent way to use Mongo?

If I were to stick with postgres, should everything belong_to the top level Account model (with indexes)?  If so, how would I handle joins?  Is it possible to perform mult-index joins (total postgres noob)?

We have about 60k entries in one table so far, yet a single account may only have 200-1000, so I'm worried about joining on the entire table.

Really appreciate any help.

Update:

We ended up moving to a VPS (Rackspace Cloud) and implementing postgres's schemas.  No regrets with this move as it runs *much* faster than it did on Heroku, and we have more control of the server.

Comment: When doing multi-tenant apps everyone everyone just scopes everything under an account-like table, nothing new on that, it's much simpler to handle replication and even sharding when you do it like this instead of the multi-schema solution. About joins, it does, but joins are always expensive, no matter what.

Comment: There's not enough detail in the question to answer it. Just telling us that you "have a multi-tenant app" is not enough information to help you decide what kind of data store to use. Either may be perfectly appropriate. How many tables do you have? How "relational" is your data?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares thanks.  So, just add an account_id to every table and index them is what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, that's how its usually doe.

Comment: That creates a lot of additional indexes. Now every query you're running against almost every field on those tables has to be filtered by account id adding more complexity and size to your index structure and query plans. Schemas avoid the need for all of those indexes and simplify all of your queries dramatically. Schemas are the optimal architecture, Heroku just needs to find a way to solve their backups issue. The other option is rather than relying on their backups for your main database, to create a low powered follower to be backed up. This would provide a live backup too.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this gem which was written to do multi-tenancy with postgres http://railscraft.tumblr.com/post/21421806379/multi-tenanting-ruby-on-rails-applications-on-heroku